# How to impose common constraint on class with javax.validation library?

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am using Bean Validation constraints to validate class instances at run time. I have many DTOs where each has multiple fields often with a common constraint. I want to add a constraint to the class so that it applies to all the properties of the class. (As lombok @NotNull constraint).

e.g

```
class Person {
@NotNull
private String name;
@NotNull
private String address;
@NotNULL
private String contact;
}
```

I want to make it something like this.

```
@NotNull
class Person {
private String name;
private String address;
private String contact
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with plain Bean Validation. So just adding `@NotNull` to the class won't work.

One potential approach could be to utilize XML configuration. The idea would be to have your own annotation `MyNotNull`. Your framework would need to scan for these annotations and build the programmatic configuration for the class in question. This could for example be done via a annotation processor during compile time. Once you have the constraint mapping XML files add them to your jar and reference them in *validation.xml*. That's just a basic idea. Personally, I am not sure whether it is worth the effort.